# strace "out of order"

Tags: process, linux-kernel, strace, fcntl

I have mostly used strace to find out why processes seemed to be hanged up and it has been very effective.  But now I am using it to analyze why some locking in a c program doesn't seem to be working.  When I run it on the actual problem program I see each process locking a certain file with fcntl with the option that is supposed to make late-comer processes wait for the previous process to unlock. strace seems to show that each process just proceeds through even though the lock is in place.

However, I made my own c program to fork 4 processes and if the process is a child process, it locks /tmp/test.txt, appends a few lines to it, and then unlocks the file.  Then I run that with strace, and I see results that are in an order that I would have thought impossible.  Again, going by the strace, each process seems to proceed through the fcntl lock even if another process already has it locked.  Also, each process seems to do the write to the file AFTER that process has done the unlock.

There seems to be some level of complexity in how the process runs that I am having trouble finding documentation for.  Can someone help me get on the right track?

By the way, I have examined the fcntl commands used and they seem to be very standard usage and each parameter checks out with the documentation.  I'm using Centos 6.6.

Answer (score 0):

On what basis are you saying

> each process seems to proceed through the fcntl lock even if another process already has it locked

There is no option in strace to print the timestamp in cpu cycles so that you can find the difference in time between two system calls.

For example,

> [pid 11778] 10:38:19.729429 <... read resumed> "", 4096) = 0
>
> [pid 11783] 10:38:19.729443 write(1, "\33[?1049h\33[?1h\33=\r", 16 >

In the above output, the time stamp is the time at which strace printed the output and not the exact instant when the system call completed. So we can never say whether the first event happened earlier or later in reality than second event.

Comment: Thanks Nithan.  I'm re-checking the timing in the strace.  Old brain circuits are waking up slowly.